# Java : TCP Socket, can the server make the first request first?

Tags: java, sockets, server, request, client

Following this diagram, I managed to connect a client with its server, and communicate perfectly :

[image: TCP Diagram]

The question is : Is it possible to let the server make first the request first?
If yes, how can I configure the client to keep waiting for the Server's call?

I did this (client's side) :

```
Socket serverSocket = new Socket(Network.serverInetAddress, Network.SERVICE_PORT);

while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(serverSocket.getInputStream()));
    MessageContent messageContent = (MessageContent) objectInputStream.readObject();

    Network.processMessage(messageContent);
}

serverSocket.close();
```

But the client did not receive the server's message, although I didn't see any error in my client or server's logs.

How can I solve this, and "broadcast" a message from the server to all connected clients? Thank You! :)

Comment: Request? You want data transfer or connection? If transfer -- just do `socket.read(...)` on client side -- you don't need `ServerSocket` on client. If you want server to initiate connection -- then it's not a server anymore, its a client :)

Comment: Thank you @VictorSorokin, I didn't find the socket's read() method. Please, what is the exact name?

Comment: `socket.getInputStream().read(...)`

Comment: Thank you @VictorSorokin :), you are the man.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its, possible. You should indicate client that must wait to server message (you can do it by read command on socket because it's blocking command).
At the server, the only you have to do is wite data after client connection accept.